# Swift Alamofire building error Identifier Name Violation

Tags: swift, alamofire

Trying to build Alamofire, but get a error `Identifier Name Violation: Variable name should start with a lowercase character: 'W' (identifier_name)` in this function

```
var readableDescription: String {
        let W = isCellular ? "W" : "-"
        let R = isReachable ? "R" : "-"
        let c = isConnectionRequired ? "c" : "-"
        let t = contains(.transientConnection) ? "t" : "-"
        let i = contains(.interventionRequired) ? "i" : "-"
        let C = contains(.connectionOnTraffic) ? "C" : "-"
        let D = contains(.connectionOnDemand) ? "D" : "-"
        let l = contains(.isLocalAddress) ? "l" : "-"
        let d = contains(.isDirect) ? "d" : "-"
        let a = contains(.connectionAutomatic) ? "a" : "-"

        return "\(W)\(R) \(c)\(t)\(i)\(C)\(D)\(l)\(d)\(a)"
    }
```

and few this error `Type Name Violation: Type name should only contain alphanumeric characters: '_URLEncodedFormEncoder' (type_name)` in name `final class _URLEncodedFormEncoder`

maybe i something disable in project ? before i didnt saw this errors

Comment: It means that `let W ` should be `let w` insteand. BUT that seems to be related to Swiftlint, no? Or any other linter, not Alamofire. Set the settings of Swiftlint to not lint your CocoaPods/Carthage, any third party lib. See https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/1423

Comment: @Larme yeah, it is swiftlint. Thank you. U can post a answer, i will accept them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually want to ignore your dependencies in your formatting and listing tools. To do so for SwiftLint, add your dependency directory to your SwiftLint excluded list. For example, if you're using CocoaPods:

```yaml
excluded: # paths to ignore during linting. Takes precedence over `included`.
   - Pods
```